# Transforming data structure

Tags: r, matrix, vector, panel, transformation

Problem: 
How to generate a new dataset from an existing one.

I have a non-trivial amount of data, of which I offer a simplified version below. The data is on individuals, where I have their sex, country of origin, and the sector and occupation they work in.

I would like to:
1. create a column in which I all sector X occupation combinations stored.
2. for each such sector X occupation, count how many females there are, how many males, and how many from each country.

```
id      <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
occupation <- c(11,12,11,12,11)
sector <- c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b")
sex     <- c(0,1,0,1,0)
country <- c(1,2,3,2,1)
data    <- data.frame(id, occupation, sector, sex, country)

id  occupation sector sex country 
1   11          a      0    1       
2   12          b      1    2       
3   11          a      0    3        
4   12          a      1    2        
5   11          b      0    1
```

This is what I would like to obtain:

```
  occXsector sex0 sex1 country1 country2 country3
1   11-a     0    2    1        0        1
2   11-b     0    1    1        0        0
3   12-a     1    0    0        1        0
4   12-b     1    0    0        1        0
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to clean up your input/output, that is, the expected output you show does not make sense from the input you give, but give this a try

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
  mutate(occXsector = paste(occupation, sector, sep="-")) %>%
  gather(key, value, sex, country) %>%
  mutate(newvalue = paste(key, value, sep="")) %>%
  group_by(occXsector) %>%
  count(newvalue) %>%
  spread(newvalue, n, fill=0)

# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   occXsector [5]
  occXsector country1 country2 country3  sex0  sex1
*      <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1       11-a        1        0        0     1     0
2       11-b        1        0        0     1     0
3       11-c        0        0        1     1     0
4       12-a        0        1        0     0     1
5       12-b        0        1        0     0     1
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great! I will take some time to wrap my head around what you did there, but it's awesome.